# Why am I able to login into Cockpit web UI even though I disabled PAM and password authentication?

Tags: ssh, security, pam

I have these settings on my remote machine under /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
PermitRootLogin no
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM no
```

The reason I did that is because I previously only wanted to be able to remotely connect via ssh with my public key installed.

But then I was curious about trying [cockpit](https://cockpit-project.org/), installed it, and logged in successfully. But why did it work?

This [stack answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/239977/is-accessing-cockpit-through-ssh-tunnel-secure/239979#239979) directed me [here](https://cockpit-project.org/guide/latest/authentication.html#initial-auth) stating that cockpit runs as a PAM module.  But if I disabled PAM, why does it let me still log in via the web interface?

Comment: You have changed the _SSH server_ configuration. It is _entirely_ unrelated to anything that does not use SSH.

Comment: Ok, so that means if I have cockpit enabled and running, it just ignores my ssh settings.  If that is correct, the using cockpit web UI defeats the purpose of me connecting via ssh with only public key as a security measure.  It seems like using cockpit is a security downgrade. Am I correct? I don't think there is a way to force it to use ssh keys as a login method.

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable password authentication in PAM, not SSH.

For my distribution, Fedora, the solution was to comment add line in `/etc/pam.d/cockpit` to disable PAM authentication for Cockpit alltogether:

```
auth       required     pam_deny.so
```